# Trying to write a TempConverter from Fahrenheit to Celsius; But it just doesnt go and just writes 0 in all cases

Tags: c#

```
using System;      

class TemperatureConverter
{
    static void Main()
    {    
        //Tc = temperature in degrees Celsius
        //Tf = temperature in degrees Fahrenheit   

        Console.WriteLine("What is the Celsius Temperature: ");
        int Tf = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        float Tc;

        Console.WriteLine("Temperature in Celsius is  {0} ", Tc = (5 / 9) * (Tf - 32));    
    }
}
```

I guess i dont i have a long way to go into the whole thing - can't figure out what did i mess up.

Comment: 5/9 is integer division and that's why is 0

Comment: Obviously someone has done it before me - i just realised - my first day around - thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`5 / 9` performs and integer division. use `d` literal on one of the operands so it will perform double precision division and give you the expected result.

```
Tc = (5d / 9) * (Tf - 32)
```

Comment: Thank you so much  - you saved the day :D. Hope i get used to this faster :).